# How to insert html code dynamically using JSTL?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I was learning **[JSTL]** and stuck at a point where I've a `String` that contains HTML code.

Following is the code I am writing and the out I'm achieving.

```
<c:set var = "str" scope = "session" value = "<div><b>Hello</b></div>"/>  
<c:out value="${str}"></c:out>
```

Output is:

```
<div><b>Hello</b></div>
```

But, actual output I want is: **Hello**

I am achieving this output when using java code in my [JSP]. As it is not a good practice to write java code in `JSP` page therefore `JSTL` is required.

**Update:** I was exploring `JSTL` and found something called **escapeXml**. This attribute can be used with `<c:out>` to use HTML/XML content.

Here is the example for that:

```
<c:set var = "str" scope = "session" value = "<div><b>Hello</b></div>"/>
<c:out value="${str}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

With this, I was able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**First download/implement the libary** [Taglibs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5)

Then a simple import at the start of the *.jsp page.

- `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

Then you are able to impirt the file

- `<c:import url="./mypage.jsp" var="cPage" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>`

**or** a absulute link, maybe a hostet html file:

- `<c:import url="www.w3schools.org/index.html" var="cPage" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>`

> 'cPage' is the string which is returned back

Afterwards get used of the var

- `<c:out value="${cPage}" escapeXml="false"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Its either

```
<c:set var = "str" scope = "session" value = "Hello"/>  
<div><b><c:out value="${str}" /></b></div>
```

Or just

```
<c:set var = "str" scope = "session" value = "<div><b>Hello</b></div>"/>  
${str}
```

Comment: Hello! I was exploring more on JSTL and got something with which I was able to get the desired result. And I've updated the same in my question. I thought, It will be better to inform you too on this as it will also help you.